# Is there any way to connect to the VPN from the EC2 windows instance?

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-ruby

I have a vpn connection for a company. I want to open that vpn connection in a ec2 windows server to open their private url in a ec2 windows server. I am looking for some manual solution. After that, I am planning to do the same connection using aws sdk with ruby.

Any help?

Comment: The question is bit ambiguous. Do you want to connect to the VPN from the EC2 windows instance?

Comment: @SAUJ ,yes you got it right.

Answer (score 1):

Since, your requirement is to connect to a custom VPN from the EC2 windows box, you can simply use a VPN client. Most popular one would be [Cisco AnyConnect](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client-v4-x/model.html) and if you need a Open-Source one, I can suggest [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/download/community-downloads.html)

Comment: Any idea if  i have ec2 instance object and want to connect with my private network programatically , thanks in advance